# Find the inverse function in R

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that generates the inverse of a given function? 
To be more specific: I have a polynomial of a third order and I need the inverse of it. It's strictly monotonously.

I read a few times that uniroot and/or polyroot can help. But how? Uniroot yields the root of a function and polyroot the zeros of a function. How can I use that for the inverse?
Maybe a dumb question but I don't get it..

Comment: To inverse a function **y = f(x)** you have to find the root of **(y - f(x))** (i.e. for a given **y** you have to search for **x**, so that **y - f(x) = 0**)

Comment: @jogo Maybe I got it, thanks! In case of a strictly monotonously function there is only one root, right? So uniroot will fulfill the task?

Comment: P.S.: I'm not an english native speaker so root is obviously the x-value where the function drops to zero. I always thought a root is the result of e.g. sqrt(4)..  :)

Comment: yes, general meaning of "root finding": search for  x-values droping the function to zero; special case (e.g. square root): **x=sqrt(4)** is the solution of **y - x² = 0** where **y=4**

Comment: @jogo Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package investr is able to apply an inverse regression.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late reply, but you could try using this function:

```
inverse = function(fn, interval = NULL, lower = min(interval), upper = max(interval), ...){
    Vectorize(function(y){
        uniroot(f=function(x){fn(x)-y}, lower=lower, upper=upper, ...)$root
    })
}
```

I've seen variants of this a few times, but never with Vectorize built in. I put the function above together to hopefully be a little more user friendly, e.g.:

```
x = 1:10
y = sqrt(x)
sqrt.inv = inverse(sqrt, lower=1, upper=10)
sqrt.inv(y)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Hope that helps!